# Сортировка Araylist при обьединении по условию

Tags: java, сортировка, arraylist

```java
List<Report> total = new ArrayList<>(reportTrue);
total.addAll(reportFalse);

total.sort(Comparator.comparing(Report::getMonth)
    .thenComparing(Report::isTrue, Comparator.reverseOrder()) // true before false
);
```

Сортирует два списка по месяцу, по условию полей `isExpense` их объектов, `true` перед `false`.

Как изменить, чтобы была эта же сортировка, но чтобы  объект с полем `true` был первым, если у этого обьекта сумма getSum() больше, чем у объекта с `false`, и наоборот.

Comment: Приведите хоть какие-то данные о своем объекте и о сортировке.  В классе `Report` есть ещё поле `sum`, по которому также надо сортировать в обратном порядке?

Comment: не в обратном порядке, а исходя из  числа которое есть у обьекта.  Обьект состоит из   int-месяц   double-число  boolean-true или false в зависимости какое ему задано состояние. если число у обьеста с тру больше чем у обьекта с фолсом то он будет выше а под ним фолс . И наоборот. Порядок там такой 01( месяц это 01,02..)  число  тру  01 число  фолс 02 число  тру  02  число  фолс и т.д

Comment: А где поле `sum` из оригинального вопроса?  Достаточно сортировать по его значению, или нужно как-то ещё суммировать в пределах одного месяца / флага `true/false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По идее достаточно просто добавить условие о сортировке по полю getSum в обратном порядке:

```
total.sort(Comparator
    .comparing(Report::getMonth)
    .thenComparing(Report::getSum, Comparator.reverseOrder())
    .thenComparing(Report::isFlag, Comparator.reverseOrder()) // true before false
);
total.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Для тестовых данных:

```
List<Report> listTrue = Arrays.asList(
        new Report(1, true, 10), new Report(1, true, 25), 
        new Report(2, true, 20), new Report(3, true, 10), 
        new Report(5, true, 20)
);

List<Report> listFalse = Arrays.asList(
        new Report(1, false, 30), new Report(2, false, 5),
        new Report(2, false, 15), new Report(5, false, 25)
);
```

Результат:

```
Report(month=1, flag=false, sum=30)
Report(month=1, flag=true, sum=25)
Report(month=1, flag=true, sum=10)
Report(month=2, flag=true, sum=20)
Report(month=2, flag=false, sum=15)
Report(month=2, flag=false, sum=5)
Report(month=3, flag=true, sum=10)
Report(month=5, flag=false, sum=25)
Report(month=5, flag=true, sum=20)
```

Comment: Проверил, вроде работает , спасибо большое